# Problems on subspace topology and basis for a topology

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Need some help here. In Ex 2.35, I know that this is question of subspace topology and the basic definition is if there is $X$ which is a space with topology $T$ and $Y$ is a subset of $X$. $T$ induces a topology $TY$ on $Y$, called the subspace topology on Y, given by $TY:= \{V\text{ is a subset of }Y|\text{there exists }U\text{ in }T, \text{ s.t. }V =\text{intersection of } U\text{ and }Y\}$. Here, $Z$ is a subset of Y which means the subspace topology on Z, i.e. $Tz := \{V \text{ is a subset of }Z|\text{there exists }U \text{ in }TY,\text{ s.t. }V =\text{intersection of }U , Y \text{ and }Z\}$. Same thing for $Z$ as a subset of $X$, but how to show they will be same?

Also, can you give some examples of a topology which has a basis? I am unclear as to the pairs which are going to form a basis.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: I d.k. what your Q about bases means. Any topology $T$ has a base (basis). E.g. $T$ itself is a base for $T$.... If $T$ is a topology on $X,$ and $B$ is a base for $T, $ and $Y\subset X,$ then $\{b\cap Y: b\in B\}$ is a base for the subspace topology on $Y.$

Comment: How do i check that condition? B is a base or basis for T. Let’s say, T is a topology which contains an empty set, {0} and the naturals. Is this a basis too?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Topologies_on_sets     Section 3.1...... See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_topology#B

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that all the open sets in X intersect with Z is the same as those open sets intersect with Y and Z. Since Z is a subset of Y, i.e. also the same as those open sets in X intersect with Z:

Let $T_X$ be the topology of X. The topology of $Y \subset X$ is $T_{XY} = \{O \cap Y, \forall O \in T_X\}$, the topology of $Z \subset X$ is $T_{XZ} = \{O \cap Z, \forall O \in T_X\}$, and the topology of $Z \subset Y$ is $T_{YZ} = \{O \cap Z, \forall O \in T_{XY}\} = \{O \cap Z \cap Y, \forall O \in T_{X}\} = \{O \cap Z, \forall O \in T_{X}\} = T_{XZ}$.

You could simply let $X = \mathbb{R}, Y = [0,2), Z = (0,1]$ and see how open sets act on those subsets.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you wrote $T_{YZ}=$ $\{O\cap Z: O\in T_{XY}\}=$ $\{(O'\cap Y)\cap Z: O'\in T_X\}=$ $=\{O'\cap (Y\cap Z): O'\in T_X\}=$ $\{O'\cap Z:O'\in T_X\}=$ $T_{XZ}.$

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\mathcal{T}_Y$ the subspace topology on $Y$, inherited from $(X,\mathcal{T})$.

So $$\mathcal{T}_Y = \{O \cap Y: O \in \mathcal{T}\}$$

Likewise for $Z$ w.r.t. $X$:

$$\mathcal{T}_Z = \{O \cap Z: O \in \mathcal{T}\}$$

and we can also consider the subspace topology on $Z$ that it inherits from $\mathcal{T}_Y$:

$$\mathcal{T}' := \{O \cap Z: O \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$$.

It's easy to see that $\mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T}_Z$, by showing two inclusions:
let $U \in \mathcal{T}'$ then $U= O \cap Z$ with $O \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ so by definition $O = O' \cap Y$ with $O' \in \mathcal{T}$. But then

$$O' \cap Z = O' \cap (Y \cap Z)=(O' \cap Y) \cap Z = O \cap Z = U$$

so that $U \in \mathcal{T}_Z$. Note that $Z= Z \cap Y$ follows as $Z \subseteq Y$.

And if $U \in \mathcal{T}_Z$, write $U = O \cap Z$ with $O \in \mathcal{T}$. Then $O \cap Y \in \mathcal{T}_Y$ and so

$$\mathcal{T}' \ni (O \cap Y) \cap Z = O\cap (Y \cap Z)=O \cap Z=U$$

and we've shown the other inclusion.

The remarks on "bases" are irrelevant for the stated problem. This is just a simple equality of certain families of subsets $\mathcal{T}'$ and $\mathcal{T}_Z$.

Comment: I think I made a mistake Sharing the two problems at a time without specifying their numbers. I’m sorry, the question of bases is a separate question, it’s not related to this. I just need to give examples of a topology which has a basis in it. That’s what I meant.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun write a separate question for the basis one.

Answer (score 0):

Z subset Y subset X.
The topology for Z subspace X, is
. . { U $\cap$ Z : U open within X }.

The topology for Z subspace Y, is
. . { U $\cap$ Z : U open within Y }.
U is open within Y when exists V
. . open within X with U = V $\cap$ Y.
Thus U $\cap$ Z = V $\cap$ Y $\cap$ Z = V $\cap$ Z
. . is open within the subspace Z.

Conversely, let U $\cap$ Z (U open within X)
. . be open within the subspace Z.
Thus U $\cap$ Y is open within Y.
Consequently, U $\cap$ Z = U $\cap$ Y $\cap$ Z
. . is open within the subspace Y of X.

Comment: This looks good. What about examples of a topology which has a basis? I am not able to get that. Need some help on that.